# Movie with a town where it is always night and the protagonist has amnesia

Tags: story-identification, movie

I can't remember the name of this fairly recent movie. The protagonist wakes up in a bath tub without memories. He breaks up with his wife, gets in touch with a "doctor" who claims to be able to help him, and is accused of serial killing prostitutes. The sun never seems to go up. The main plot device:

> The town is in perpetual darkness. It is the experiment of a hive-mind race, that tries to understand why humans are individual. To achieve this, they move humans' memories around. They can shape the world with thought, and when the protagonist learns this power, he challenges them, destroying them. It is revealed that the Earth is long since gone, and he lives on in this false world.

I've looked for titles like *City of Night* and *City of Darkness*, but can't find it.

Comment: Kiefer Sutherland as a crippled doctor... A classic!

Comment: This movie is some of the best seeming fantasy that ends up Hard SF that I've ever seen.

Comment: Any similarities to "The Matrix" are purely coincidental ;)

Comment: This is an absolutely fantastic movie...what the Matrix (which came after it) should have been.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The movie you are looking for is [*Dark City*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118929/) (1998).

> A man struggles with memories of his past, which includes a wife he cannot remember, and a nightmarish world without a sun.